# ASCII equivalent to \eqn{\bar{x}} in Rd files

Tags: r, ascii, rd

I am writing the documentation for a function of an R package I am building.

In order to have a moderately nice aspect for the help file, I need the equivalent of \bar{x} in ASCII:

```
\eqn{\bar{x}}{ASCII equivalent}
```

Comment: just call it something like `x_bar` ..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's a consensus on the best way to do this, it's more a matter of taste and clarity. 
Having faced this issue myself, two solutions I have used are:

```
y = \eqn{\bar{x}}{xbar}
y = \eqn{\bar{x}}{mean(x)}
```

The advantage of the latter is that when the help is displayed as ASCII, the user can copy/paste (send) the text to an R process, getting an example value for `y`. This assumes that `\bar{x}` is shorthand for the mean, as is often the case.

Comment: thank you. Yes, indeed, mean(x) seems more intuitive as well.